# Use PHP to echo 05 instead of just 5 as example. How do I do this?

Tags: php, date

I am using a bit of PHP right now to output how many days, hours, minutes and seconds are left until a specific date. It works great, but as of right now, it will output something like: 14:5:33:36

Ideally, if it's less than 10 I'd like it to output 05 instead of just 5. I know this must be fairly simple in PHP, but being a front end developer... I just can't quite wrap my brain around this. Below is the code I'm currently using:

```
<?
    $rem = strtotime('2013-02-01 14:00:00') - time();
    $day = floor($rem / 86400);
    $hr  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
    $min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
    $sec = ($rem % 60);
    if($day)
        echo "$day:";
    if($hr)
        echo "$hr:";
    if($min)
        echo "$min:";
    if($sec)
        echo "$sec";
?>
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What you are trying to do? find the interval? DateInterval can do that

Comment: str_pad function. Look it up

Comment: What is your PHP version BTW?

Comment: sprintf() would be another option

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that. my PHP version is 5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str_pad` with the `STR_PAD_LEFT` flag.

```
$num = 5;
echo str_pad($num, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: When I use this it outputs 0450 instead of 05 for some strange reason. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the input to `str_pad`?

Comment: The input is simply '4'. and after having just reused it, it now outputs '0444'.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I forgot to include the ':' and so it was grouping together the minutes and the hours. Haha. It's working perfectly now. Thanks for your help good sir!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($interval);
echo $interval->format("%D");
```

With format() you can format your output;

Output is like below:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 2
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 2
)
02
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class for time operations:

```
$future = new DateTime('2013-01-20 14:00:00');
$now = new DateTime('now');
echo $future->diff($now)->format('%D:%H:%I:%S'); # outputs 01:20:08:12
```

Take a look at [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) for formating interval.

Comment: This looked like the solution I might be looking for, but it kills the entire  page unfortunately. Outputs a blank page.

Comment: What version of PHP do you have? Do you have error_reporting/showing on?

Comment: I am on 5.2. I found a solution, however this baffles me a bit that it seems to have killed the entire page.

Comment: @RobertE, if you had error reporting on, you would see why entire page was killed. diff() is for PHP >= 5.3.0. Just upgrade already ;-)